# Swift 3.0: Type 'RLMResults<RLMObjectType>' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Tags: realm, swift3

I'm seeing:

> Type `RLMResults<RLMObjectType>` does not conform to protocol `Sequence`

when converting to Swift 3. I am looking for a version of Realm for Swift 3.0, however I can't find a proper one, even a branch.

I tried to write an extension, but still the same error message:

```
extension RLMResults: Sequence
{
    public func makeIterator() -> RLMResults.Iterator
    {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```

How can I fix it, or where I can find the proper framework or branch?

Update:
The code that needs Sequence protocol:

```
public class RealmChartUtils: NSObject
{
    /// Transforms the given Realm-ResultSet into an xValue array, using the specified xValueField
    public static func toXVals(results: RLMResults<RLMObject>, xValueField: String) -> [String]
    {
        let addedValues = NSMutableSet()
        var xVals = [String]()

        for object in results // <-- here needs Sequence protocol
        {
            let xVal = (object as! RLMObject)[xValueField] as! String!
            if !addedValues.contains(xVal!)
            {
                addedValues.add(xVal!)
                xVals.append(xVal!)
            }
        }

        return xVals
    }
}
```

So in swift 2.2, we added an extension like below right after above function:

```
extension RLMResults: SequenceType
{
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator
    {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}

extension RLMArray: SequenceType
{
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator
    {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

So in Xcode 8 beta 3, it says `SequenceType` is renamed to `Sequence`, however this is the original question because I tried to make above extension conforms to `Sequence` (which is my first posted extension), the compiler keeps saying `Type RLMResults<RLMObjectType> does not conform to protocol Sequence`

Could I solve this without upgrading Realm swift framework (I would rather wait a release, not self building the master branch at this moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How can I get `RLMResults` to conform to `Sequence`?

See [Using Realm Objective-C from Swift](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#using-realm-objectivec-from-swift) for information on how to make Realm Objective-C's types work more naturally from Swift. In particular, take note of the section on `RLMSupport.swift`:

> We recommend you compile the Swift/RLMSupport.swift file (which is also available in our release zip).
>
> This file adds SequenceType conformance to Realm Objective‑C collection types and re-exposes Objective‑C methods that aren’t natively accessible from Swift like methods including variadic arguments.
>
> Realm Objective‑C doesn’t include this file by default because that would force all users of Realm Objective‑C to include the hefty Swift dynamic libraries regardless of whether or not they use Swift in their app!

However, due to [a bug in the Swift 3 compiler](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1779) the conformance of `RLMResults` and `RLMArray` to `Sequence` has been temporarily disabled. Hopefully the Swift compiler issue will be resolved prior to Xcode 8 moving out of beta.

### Where I can find Realm with support for Swift 3?

Support for Swift 3 with Realm Swift is present on Realm's master branch, alongside the existing support for Swift 2. It will become available in releases of Realm Swift once Xcode 8 and Swift 3 are finalized, later this year.

Comment: it's a pure swift project, is there any way I can get rid of this error?

Comment: I don't see your answer about RLMSupport solves the issue.

Comment: If it's a pure Swift project, why are you using Realm Objective-C? Realm Swift provides an interface that conforms to the Swift protocols you'd expect out of the box. RLMSupport.swift provides the same for projects using Realm Objective-C from Swift, which is typically only useful in mixed Obj-C / Swift projects.

Comment: Hmm, it's an open source project called Charts on github. It's library is written in swift, however, there are demos using Objective-C. I am working on the swift 3.0 branch to provide a branch for developers to test iOS 10, however, I can't get rid of this error by writing an extension to conform Sequence protocol

Comment: Can you please clarify why you think RLMSupport.swift is not the solution to your problem?

Comment: Looking at this further, it looks like RLMSupport.swift's Swift 3 code disables  the conformance you're after due to compiler bugs.

Comment: I checked RLMSupport.swift code, and it comments out the two extensions I am trying to, and had a comment: `// TODO: Figure out why this causes the Swift 3 compiler to segfault.` Seems we are talking about the same issue here.

Comment: From the most recent edit to my answer: "However, due to [a bug in the Swift 3 compiler](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1779) the conformance of RLMResults and RLMArray to Sequence has been temporarily disabled. Hopefully the Swift compiler issue will be resolved prior to Xcode 8 moving out of beta". Due to the nature of the problem I think you'll have to wait for the compiler issue to be resolved before you can have `RLMResults` conform to `Sequence`.

Comment: No, the compiler error you're seeing is different than the segfault the comment in the code talks about. Your compiler error is because your return type is incorrect given your implementation (should be `NSFastEnumerationIterator`, not `RLMResults.Iterator`).

Comment: oh I see, this is different. Because I have no idea what RLMResults.Iterator is, so I used the code from swift 2.2 and replaced with

Comment: is there a github issue or anything I can follow when it is solved?

Comment: I linked to the ticket tracking the Swift compiler bug above. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3746 tracks reenabling conformance to `Sequence` in RLMSupport.swift once the Swift compiler bug is resolved.